# Reference request for type of specific integral equation in two variable:

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, integral-transforms

Consider the following integral equation:

> $$\int_0^\infty K(t,y)\phi(t,x)dt=0$$

Here, $K(t,y)$ is a trigonometric kernel and
$\phi(t,x)$ is monotonic wrt $x$ ( for fixed $t$).

I want to find the dependence of $y$ on $x$, i.e. $y=f(x)$.

> I want some methods and references on how to deal with such problems in general.

Comment: you could solve this numerically, but without more information on the kernels further progress seems unlikely.